# python adding a class object to a list

Tags: python

Im trying to create an empty instance of my class object and add it to a list, however, as soon as i try to create the object add new data i get an error for it as seen below:

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pagerduty.py", line 96, in <module>
    UserData = User()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

code

```
class User(object):
    __attrs = ['Policy','Level', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'StartTime',
               'EndTime', 'Name', 'Mobile']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr, None))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            ['%s: %r' % (attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self.__attrs])  

OnCallData = [] 
for User in objPolicyData['users']: 
    UserData = User()     
    UserData.Name = User['name']
    UserData.Mobile = UserMobile = getUserMobile(User['id']) 
    for OnCall in User['on_call']:    
        UserPolicy = OnCall['escalation_policy'] 
        PolicyName = UserPolicy['name']
        if PolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:
            UserData.Policy = PolicyName
            UserData.Level = OnCall['level']
            UserData.StartDate = getDate(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndDate = getDate(OnCall['end'])
            UserData.StartTime = getTime(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndTime = getTime(OnCall['end'])    
OnCallData.append(UserData)
```

Comment: both your class and the variable you iterate over is called `User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `for` scope, the `User` identifier is the iterated value from `objPolicyData['users']` (as you used it in `UserData.Name = User['name']`)

you need to use a diffierent name for the iteration.
something like that:

```
for userI in objPolicyData['users']: 
    UserData = User()     
    UserData.Name = userI['name']
    UserData.Mobile = UserMobile = getUserMobile(userI['id']) 
    for OnCall in userI['on_call']:    
        UserPolicy = OnCall['escalation_policy'] 
        PolicyName = UserPolicy['name']
        if PolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:
            UserData.Policy = PolicyName
            UserData.Level = OnCall['level']
            UserData.StartDate = getDate(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndDate = getDate(OnCall['end'])
            UserData.StartTime = getTime(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndTime = getTime(OnCall['end'])
```

Note that using the conventions could prevent this bug for you. meaning, starting the name of a variable with lower case letter (`user`) and a class with capital letter (`User`).
this is relevant for most of your variables names

Answer (score 2):

Both your class and the variable you are iterating over is called `User`. Change one of them to a different name.

By convention in python variable names are lowercase. So I suggest the following change:

```
for user in objPolicyData['users']: 
    user_data = User()     
    user_data.name = User['name']
    user_data.mobile = UserMobile = getUserMobile(User['id']) 
    for on_call in User['on_call']:    
        user_policy = on_call['escalation_policy'] 
        policy_name = user_policy['name']
        if policy_name.lower().find('test') == -1:
            user_data.policy = policy_name
            user_data.level = on_call['level']
            user_data.start_date = get_date(on_call['start'])
```

and so on. This follows the naming conventions in [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This will also take care of your error.

Of course if there is already an established style guide you should follow it and decide for a different name of `User` (the iteration variable).